# how to put < > and double space or multiple space in my html tag or in my element

Tags: html, html-entities

how can I put <>'' or more space in html tag <>

this is my code that have problem.

```html
<div>
  <p> > or < </p>
</div>
```

Comment: less than: `&lt;` greater than: `&gt;` , space: `&nbsp;`

Answer (score 2):

You can use [HTML entities to render HTML's reserved characters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Entity):

- `&lt;` = `<`
- `&gt;` = `>`
- `&amp;` = `&`
- `&quot;` = `"`
- `&nbsp;` = [Non-breaking space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space)

---

The `&nbsp;` entity is useful because browsers [will collapse consecutive whitespace characters](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-text-3/#segment-break) into one (so `<p>Foo bar</p>` and `<p>Foo    bar</p>` will appear the same, but `<p>Foo&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;bar</p>` will have the extra space).

<sub>...however you should not use `&nbsp;` for element spacing and layout (instead use CSS's `margin` and `padding`), and if you really do want non-collapsed whitespace then [consider using CSS's `white-space` with `pre`, `pre-wrap`, or `break-spaces`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-text-3/#white-space-property) (as only those values will *not* collapse consecutive spaces and tabs, while `normal`, `nowrap`, and `pre-line` will collapse spaces).</sub>

---

```html
<div>
  <p> &gt;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;or&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&lt; </p>
</div>
```